# How to run SVN commands using MonoDevelop and Visual SVN server

Tags: svn, version-control, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, visualsvn-server

I'm using MonoDevelop for iPhone development with MonoTouch.  I use Visual SVN server (free) on my Windows Server 2008 R2 server.  All works great with source code control, however, I'm not sure how to do other source code commands that are available with the SVN sub-system.

Can someone explain how to run SVN commands while using MonoDevelop and/or Visual SVN server from a remote system such as being used for development?  I'd like to branch my release, etc.  I looked at the Visual SVN web site and the SVN help area but I don't know how/where to run those commands.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, you can right-click on the root node in the GUI and find the option to launch the command line from Visual SVN server.  http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00013/

Answer (score -1):

You use a command line svn client, like the [slik svn](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download).

You could also use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/).

Both those tools operates with the same local working copy as MonoDevelop.